# Checking if a value appears in both a string and a dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, key

As a part of a larger problem, I have to write a function that checks whether all the letters in a given **word** appear in a dictionary called **hand** (and also in a wordlist, but I'm omitting that part for here), and make sure that if a letter appears twice, for example, in the word, it has to appear at least as many times in the dictionary. Here's one of the functions I wrote:

```
def is_valid_word(word, hand):
    for let in word:
        if let in hand.keys():
            if hand[let]>=word.count(let):
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

I also tried this way:

```
def is_valid_word(word, hand):
    for let in word:
        if let not in hand.keys():
            return False
        else:                                 #in another variation I merged 
            if hand[let]>=word.count(let):    # these two lines with _elif_
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

In other similar functions I didn't specifically wrote **hand.keys()**, but just went with

```
if let in/not in hand
```

Still every time I tried the function with

```
print is_valid_word("account", {"a":1, "c":1, "l":2, "n":1, "o":3, "r":2, "t":1, "y":1})
```

it would return True even though the letter "c" appears twice in the word but only once in the dictionary (I also tried the word "rupture" with differently worded dictionaries, but the second example I've given here deals with it the way it's supposed to, unlike the others).
Any ideas what to do?

**Edit**: this is the way it's explained in the problem, hope it makes it more understandable:

"A valid word is in the word list; and it is composed entirely of letters from the current hand.
Implement the is_valid_word function.

```
def is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):
"""Returns True if word is in the word_list and is entirely 
composed of letters in the hand. Otherwise, returns False.
Does not mutate hand or word_list.
word: string
hand: dictionary (string -> int)
word_list: list (string)
"""
# TO DO ... "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I didn't misunderstand you want to check whether all the letters of a word is the key of a dict and the related value in the dict is greater than the appearance times of the letter in the word. Unfortunately, your program has an obvious bug. It terminates the loop only after check the first letter.

After modification it should look like this:

```
def is_valid_word(word, hand):
    for let in word:
        if let in hand and hand[let]>=word.count(let):
            continue
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The function returns the result of the first letter in word -- which terminates the function.  The `for` loop will not execute past the first letter.

Modify the function so that it returns `True` only if *all* the letters are valid.  (It's okay to still return `False` on the first invalid letter.)

Comment: The issue isn't the loop mechanism; the issue is that you always `return True` or `return False` after inspecting the _first_ letter, which terminates the function.

Comment: Gotcha. Will see what I can do

Answer (score 0):

I would use `all` and `collections.Counter` to make it straight forward.

```
>>> def is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):
...     if word in word_list:
...         return all(letter_dict[letter] >= hand[letter] for letter in Counter(word) if letter in hand ) 
>>>     return False
```

Comment: haven't studied these concepts yet, but will check them out right away. Thank you!